# Dynamically validate all radio inputs are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, radio-group

I've got many inputs in a table. I want to validate each time i get in the page that if all the `radioOpciones*` have one option checked. If it's true, I will `show()` something.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      title
    </th>
    <td class="radioGroup">
      <input id="radioOpciones1" value="1" name="radioOpciones1" checked="checked" type="radio">
    </td>
    <td class="radioGroup">
      <input id="radioOpciones2" value="2" name="radioOpciones1" type="radio">
    </td>
    <td class="radioGroup">
      <input id="radioOpciones3" value="3" name="radioOpciones1" type="radio">
    </td>
    <td class="radioGroup">
      <input id="radioOpciones4" value="4" name="radioOpciones1" type="radio">
    </td>
    <td class="radioGroup">
      <input id="radioOpciones5" value="5" name="radioOpciones1" type="radio">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      title2
    </th>
    <td class="radioGroup">
      <input id="radioOpciones6" value="1" name="radioOpciones2" checked="checked" type="radio">
    </td>
    <td class="radioGroup">
      <input id="radioOpciones7" value="2" name="radioOpciones2" type="radio">
    </td>
    <td class="radioGroup">
      <input id="radioOpciones8" value="3" name="radioOpciones2" type="radio">
    </td>
    <td class="radioGroup">
      <input id="radioOpciones9" value="4" name="radioOpciones2" type="radio">
    </td>
    <td class="radioGroup">
      <input id="radioOpciones10" value="5" name="radioOpciones2" type="radio">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I was trying to get the length by

```
$('.radioGroup').length
```

and then compare with checked options

```
$('.radioGroup:has(input:checked)').length
```

I want to get when i click in each radio that if it's the last radio option checked possible to send a continue button.

Comment: The validation seems redundant, as you set `checked` on the first radio in the group by default, therefore it's not possible for anything to ever be unchecked and hence, invalid.

Comment: But for the first time that i enter in the page, maybe i've got some question checked or maybe all aren't checked, so, i want to validate each time i click on radio that if it's the last option checked to send a continue button.

Comment: That's my point, you have set `checked` on the elements, so there is no possibility for them to be unchecked. If the HTML in the question is inaccurate, then you should edit it

Comment: You cannot have duplicate IDs

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have no problem with the checked on the elements because when i reload the page, the input get selected dinamically by DB.
The problem is how i could get dinamically that the whole inputs have at least one checked in each name (i can't know how much names are because it's dinamically).

Comment: That makes no sense. Again, you're selecting one *by default*. There will *never be any unselected*. Alternatively, if you're expecting to be able to select all radios within the group, that's also not possible. This is why your question makes so little sense.

Comment: Simply create a `<radio-group>` web component that you can ask for `value`. If that `value` is `null`, you know none of the radiobuttons of that group is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Search for distinct radio input names, pass them to `checkRadioGroups()` function and get results.

You can use this function each time you want to check the `checked` state of the radio inputs.

**NOTE**

You can use this approach in any possible HTML structure.

```js
function checkRadioGroups(collection) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var i in collection) {
    var nameAttr = collection[i];
    var isChecked = $('input[name="' + nameAttr + '"]:checked').length > 0;
    obj[nameAttr] = isChecked;
  }
  return obj;
}

function getDistinctGroupNames() {
    var names = [];
    $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(index, elem) {
        var name = $(elem).attr('name');
        if (names.indexOf(name) === -1) {
            names.push(name);
        }
    });
    return names;
}

var check = checkRadioGroups(getDistinctGroupNames());
console.log(check);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>
          title
        </th>
        <td class="radioGroup">
          <input id="radioOpciones1" value="1" name="radioOpciones1" checked="checked" type="radio">
        </td>
        <td class="radioGroup">
          <input id="radioOpciones1" value="2" name="radioOpciones1" type="radio">
        </td>
        <td class="radioGroup">
          <input id="radioOpciones1" value="3" name="radioOpciones1" type="radio">
        </td>
        <td class="radioGroup">
          <input id="radioOpciones1" value="4" name="radioOpciones1" type="radio">
        </td>
        <td class="radioGroup">
          <input id="radioOpciones1" value="5" name="radioOpciones1" type="radio">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          title2
        </th>
        <td class="radioGroup">
          <input id="radioOpciones2" value="1" name="radioOpciones2" type="radio">
        </td>
        <td class="radioGroup">
          <input id="radioOpciones2" value="2" name="radioOpciones2" type="radio">
        </td>
        <td class="radioGroup">
          <input id="radioOpciones2" value="3" name="radioOpciones2" type="radio">
        </td>
        <td class="radioGroup">
          <input id="radioOpciones2" value="4" name="radioOpciones2" type="radio">
        </td>
        <td class="radioGroup">
          <input id="radioOpciones2" value="5" name="radioOpciones2" type="radio">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Tried to be generic. User can use this function in another HTML structure

Comment: There's a small problem, i don't know the number of 'radioOpciones' or radioGroups as u call, that i could have, could be dinamic?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Now, you can detect any group name in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$(function() {

    var radios = $('input[type=radio][name*=radioOpciones]').filter(function() {
        return $(this).is(':checked')
    });
    alert(radios.length);

});
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd address this using a `<radio-group>` webcomponent. The element represents the missing radio-group element which you can simply ask for the value. `null` means none of the radio buttons is `:checked`. Otherwise, the radio-group element reports the value of the `:checked` radiobutton:

```js
class RadioGroup extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(...args) {
    const self = super(...args)
    self.type = 'radio-group'
    self.radioButtons = null
    return self
  }

  get value() {
    const checked = this.querySelector(':checked')
    return checked ? checked.value : null
  }

  set value(val) {
    const radios = this.radioButtons.filter(i => i.value === val)
    if (radios.length) {
      radios[0].checked = true
    } else {
      for (const radioButton of this.radioButtons) {
        radioButton.checked = false
      }
    }

    let change = createNewEvent('change', true, true)
    this.dispatchEvent(change)
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    if (this.nextSibling) { // children parsed?
      this.radioButtons = [...this.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]')]
    } else { // if not, populate radioButtons only on next animation frame
      window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        this.radioButtons = [...this.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]')]
      })
    }
  }
}

window.customElements.define('radio-group', RadioGroup)

let radioGroups = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('radio-group'))

check.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(radioGroups.every(radioGroup => radioGroup.value))
})
```

```html
<radio-group id="sex">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Sex</legend>
    <input type="radio" value="female" id="female" name="sex" />
    <label for="female">female</label>
    <input type="radio" value="male" id="male" name="sex" />
    <label for="male">male</label>
    <input type="radio" value="diverse" id="diverse" name="sex" />
    <label for="diverse">diverse</label>
  </fieldset>
</radio-group>
<radio-group id="color">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Color</legend>
    <input type="radio" value="blue" id="blue" name="color" />
    <label for="blue">blue</label>
    <input type="radio" value="red" id="red" name="color" />
    <label for="red">red</label>
    <input type="radio" value="green" id="green" name="color" />
    <label for="green">green</label>
  </fieldset>
</radio-group>
<button id="check" type="button">Check if each radiogroup has a checked radiobutton</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you need to give different id's to your inputs in same page cause of HTML rules. Because id specifies a unique id for the element. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)

And your elegant solution is here :

```
if($('input.classname').not(':checked').length > 0) {
  ...
}
```

OR

```
 if($('input[name="inputname"]').not(':checked').length > 0) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: While the duplicate Ids are an issue, your approach would seem to be less than ideal. You'd need to copy/paste the above statement N times for *every* radio.

Comment: Thanks rory, that is i am going to say.

Comment: I mentioned the id problem firstly, but if you want to force with id it is a clear solution. It should be done with class or name actually.